# Add multiple services to the IServiceCollection with a loop using reflection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, reflection, asp.net-core-webapi

During the DI container setup I have multiple services that rely on a manual setup. E.g. some of them require a database connection string. So instead of writing

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(TheInterface), typeof(TheImplementation));
```

I have to do

```
services.AddTransient<TheInterface>(serviceProvider => 
{
    // gather all the constructor parameters here
    return new TheImplementation(/* pass in the constructor parameters */);
});
```

The constructor parameters are always the same. Instead of writing this multiple times I thought about creating a collection of those services and looping through that collection. I know I can create new instances from a type by using the `Activator` class but I'm struggling with the conversion from a type to a generic. The following code is a sample code for demo purposes

```
    public void SetupServices(IServiceCollection services, string databaseConnectionString)
    {
        IDictionary<Type, Type> servicesTypes = new Dictionary<Type, Type>()
        {
            { typeof(MyInterface), typeof(MyImplementation) }
            // ... more services here
        };

        foreach (KeyValuePair<Type, Type> servicesType in servicesTypes)
        {
            services.AddTransient <??? /* servicesType.Key does not work here */> (serviceProvider =>
            {
                return Activator.CreateInstance(servicesType.Value, databaseConnectionString /*, other params */);
            });
        }
    }
```

The position I'm struggling is this line

`services.AddTransient <??? /* servicesType.Key does not work here */>`

How would I convert the service interface type to a generic one? I'm not even sure if this loop is worth the effort... but currently I have 5 services which could use it.

Comment: There are a lot of threads here, how to invoke a generic method using a `Type` variable, but it doesn't look like a good approach, IMO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure doing a generic version of it is the correct way to go. Could your 'manual setup' of your services may be fixed using the [options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.1)?  As it looks like you're trying to pass through a database connection string.

It could look something like

```cs
// Options object
public class DatabaseOptions {
   public string ConnectionString {get;set;}
}

// Startup.cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    [...]
    // From configuration (appsettings.json)
    services.Configure<DatabaseOptions>(Configuration.GetSection("Database"));
    // OR directly
    services.Configure<DatabaseOptions>(x => x.ConnectionString = "SomeString");

}

// The service
public class SomeService {
    public SomeService(IOptions<DatabaseOptions> dbOptions) {
        var connectionString = dbOptions.Value.ConnectionString;
    }
}
```

Comment: as far as I understood I can transfer the config values from the appsettings.json file into such data objects and make them accessible from everywhere? (instead of injecting the whole IConfiguration object)

Comment: You can, I just updated my answer to include to ways of setting up the option.

Answer (score 1):

You can register type using `ServiceDescriptor`:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<Type, Type> servicesType in servicesTypes)
{ 
    services.Add(new ServiceDescriptor(
        serviceType.Key, // interface
        serviceProvider => Activator.CreateInstance(servicesType.Value, databaseConnectionString /*, other params */), // implementation
        ServiceLifetime.Transient); // lifetime
    }
}
```

Comment: your solution is really good and answers my question perfectly. I'm sorry that this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63336346/13755987 seems to be a better solution for the future. But +1 :)